# Remove +- sign coming from API - in angular6 template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have an incoming value from API as `"amount": "-1232.32"`

I would like to remove this sign in HTML template, as I am directly using `*ngFor` loop inside the template and I would like to manipulate incoming value.

I tried below

```
{{Math.abs(+data.NetAmount) }}
```

Comment: You cannot directly access Math.abs in your HTML but you can create an alias like this in your TS class: `getAbs = Math.abs;` Then in your template call it like this: `{{ getAbs(+data.NetAmount) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which return the value.

```js
transformtValue(value){
  return Math.abs(value)
}
```

Then you can call the function in template

```html
transformtValue(data.NetAmount)
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to declare `Math` on your component.ts. In addition, I think Math.abs() only work on numbers, not strings.

On your component.ts,

```
Math: any = Math;
```

And on your html,

```
{{ Math.abs(Number(data.NetAmount)) }}
```

However, a better way to do it would be to create a custom pipe for that purpose.